# Reset character value to null in the same function in C

Tags: c

I'm having problem with reseting back the value of my psswrd[] to NULL, it's works fine when I return from another function but not with the same function, for example my first input is "averylonginput", because input is false, I'm gonna type again the right one which is "thepass" but the value is now "thepassnginput" in where the previous and present input have mixed up, because the new input have overlayed the previous...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

success(){
    clrscr();
    printf("Press Any Key to Go Back and Login Again");
    getch();
}

int cnt;
void login(){
char      ch,
          mypass[]="thepass",
          psswrd[256]={0};
START:
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    clreol();
    do{
        ch=getch();
        if( isprint(ch) ){
            psswrd[ cnt++ ] = ch;
            printf("%c", '#');
            }
        else
        if(ch==8 && cnt){
            psswrd[ cnt-- ] = '\0';
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
            }
    }
    while(ch!=13);
    printf("\nCurrent Password: %s",psswrd); // Check Output
    // Just an exit option
    printf("\n\nPress Any Key to Continue, ESC to exit");
    int opt;
    opt=getch();
    if(opt==27) exit(0);
    else
    //-------------------
    if(!strcmp(psswrd,mypass)){
        cnt=NULL;
        clrscr();
        printf("Success");
        }
    else{
        psswrd[NULL];
        cnt=NULL;
        goto START;
        }
     }

void main(){
LOGIN:  login();
    success();
    goto LOGIN;
    }
```

---

As the code have been fixed using `memset(psswrd, 0, sizeof(psswrd));`
What's the difference that it works without memset when I'm from another function?

Comment: You clearly know about loops, so why don't you use them instead of labels and `goto`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `psswrd[NULL]` doesn't do anything by itself. It's just the same as writing `psswrd[0]`. If you enable warnings you should get a warning about this, and maybe one because `NULL` may be a pointer and you use that as an index.

If you want to clear it, then use e.g. [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset):

```
memset(psswrd, 0, sizeof(psswrd));
```

Comment: Thanks man, it really worked, but I'm just curious what's the difference that it works without memset when I'm from another function?